# VIM creating mapping

Tags: vim, mapping

I want to create mapping that would be trgiiger in normal mode by pressing pp and I want it to execute key sequence ctr w l. How do I do that. I have now sth like this but it doesn't work.

```
nmap nn <C-w-h><CR>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have to be a lot more clearer. You mention `pp`, but your example uses `nn`. You mention the sequence Ctrl w l, but you write C-w-h in your example. Do you want the sequence to be `Crtl+W, release, press l`, or `Ctrl+W, Ctrl+L`?

Comment: I want it for eg to go to next split on left and I want mapping to be ll and it triggers pressing ctrl+w+h.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<C-w-h>` is not a valid key sequence. If you want to press <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> and then release and press <kbd>h</kbd>, you need the following:

```
:nmap nn <C-W>h
```

If you want to press <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> and then press <kbd>h</kbd> without releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (effectively <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd>), you need this:

```
:nmap nn <C-W><C-H>
```

I usually create both maps in this situation, because sometimes my fingers lag and I release Ctrl a little later or a little earlier. With both, that's not a worry.

There's no need to add a `<CR>` to the mapping here.